# Need to Connect Azure Sql db from Azure Data Factory,restricted at Schema Level using userManagedIdentity as Authentication Method

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

I have a successful connection from Azure data Factory to my Azure Sql db .And I have set the AAD Admin as myself and also the UserManagedIdentity from the portal.

Now whoever use that UserManagedidentity in ADF can access the entire Sql DB.I need to restrict the access at Schema level, like X people should have access to X tables and Y people should have access to Y Tables.

So how can we achieve this through usermangedIdentity ,Can we set Schema level permissions via usermanagedidentity?

Answer (score 0):

The managed identity has a corresponding user in SQL, so limit their permissions are you would any other user or group.

i.e.:
GRANT SELECT ON Employees TO UserManagedIdentity;

Comment: Here the UserManagedidentity is part of Admin group.Can we further restrict the identity because we are keeping the identity as one of admin

Comment: No, think about it how can you restrict access if something needs to have full access

Answer (score 0):

Admin overrides all other restrictions. So as long as a user is part of Server admin, he/she can have the entire access.
For your use case, you would need to remove the managed identity from the admin group DL, create a new user within the database and grant the new user required access